# SharePoint 2013 implement simple logout button which do not redirect to default sign out page using JavaScript client object model

Tags: sharepoint-2013, windows-authentication

I am using windows authentication in my web application.
My requirement is to implement a sign out button which will sign out the user without having him to close the browser and application should not ask him to login again.
I tried following two options:

1. Redirecting the user to default signout.aspx page `/_layouts/15/SignOut.aspx`
2. Using "Sign In as a different user" URL `/_layouts/15/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true`

In first case, user is redirected to default sign out page but he can press "Go Back to Site" link to revisit the site. Another major issue is that the user has to close the browser to sign out from the application completely, which is not desirable in my project requirement.
In second case, the the current user is signed out of the application but if the user has saved the password in browser, he gets signed in automatically to the application.

I also came across the solution where we replace the default sign out page with a custom sign out page, but I am not sure whether it can be implemented using JavaScript Client Object Model of SharePoint.

Comment: Perhaps ask this on the [Sharepoint SE site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) instead.